# Recent record list view for Visualforce Tab

Tags: visualforce

Currently I have created a custom visualforce tab for my application. When I clcik on the tab the recent record list view is not being shown. Is there any way the recent record list view can be shown on click of the visualforce tab?

I have posted my VFPage code below.

```
<apex:page standardController="KPI_Library__c" sidebar="false"  tabstyle="KPI_Repository__tab">
<apex:form title="KPI Library" >

    <apex:sectionHeader title="KPI Library" />

    <apex:pageBlock id="pageBlock" >

        <div align="center">
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" />
        </div>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="KPI Iformation" columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!KPI_Library__c.KPI_Library__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!KPI_Library__c.KPI_Sub_Library__c}"/>                      
            <apex:inputField value="{!KPI_Library__c.KPI_Name__c}"/>     
            <apex:inputField value="{!KPI_Library__c.Unit__c}">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="pageBlock" />
            </apex:inputField>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I have updated the question with my current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether I understand your requirement correctly. But to me, you shouldn't implement a VF page tab. Instead, use a standard Salesforce custom object tab and redirect view/edit of your custom object to your Visualforce page.

Comment: Can you please share an example on how to do this. I have not worked on such a scenario before.

Comment: To override the tab behavior, navigate to Setup > Create > Objects, click on the Cool Widget object's name, scroll down to "Buttons, Links, and Actions" and click edit next to the Tab. Choose the VF option, find your page in the list and click save. Done.

Comment: @user3197916 Cool, glad that you figured out yourself!